# Mongodb и поиск во вложенных документах

Tags: mongodb

Допустим есть документ коллекции такого вида:

```
{
   "objects": [
     {
       "a": 1,
       "prop":2,
     },
     {
       "a": 2,
       "prop":3
     } 
    ] 
}
```

Есть задача найти документы имеющие вложенные документы с одинаковыми свойствами. Допустим нужно найти документ который содержит два вложенных документа со свойством а == 1
Я построил условие:

```
{
    "objects": { "$elemMatch": { "$and": [ {"a":1}, { "a":1} ]} }
}
```

Этот запрос как и ожидается вернет мне документ, где есть любые вложенные документы со свойством а:1 и а = 2 и т.д.. А вот как бы составить запрос, что бы он вернул мне только те документы, где есть два вложенных документа со свойствами а=1 и их должно быть обязательно столько, сколько условий мы написали. 
В идеале должен вернуть документы только такого вида.

```
{
   "objects": [
     {
       "a": 1,
       "prop":5
     },
     {
       "a": 1,
       "prop":6 
     } 
    ] 
}
```

Буду очень признателен за любые подсказки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь следующими операторами:

- [$where](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) - выбирает документ, для которого функция вернула истину.
- [$size](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) - выбирает документ, если вложенный массив имеет заданный размер

На деле достаточно только `$where`.

Запрос:

```
db.collection.find({
    $where: function() { 
       return this.objects.length==2 && this.objects.every(function(el){
           return el.a==1;
       });
    }
})
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Рабочее решение !

Answer (score 2):

Другой вариант решения, тоже рабочий.

```
db.test.aggregate([
{
"$redact": {
  "$cond": [
    {
      "$eq": [
        {
          "$size": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$objects",
              "as": "item",
              "cond": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$item.a",
                  1
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        2
      ]
    },
    "$$KEEP",
    "$$PRUNE"
  ]
}
  }
 ])
```

Comment: `$eq:{$size:{$filter:...},2}` - запрос выберет документ с двумя `a:1` и многими `a:100500`?

Comment: совершенно верно

Comment: извиняюсь, не усмотрел... нужно $eq заменить на $gte и тогда будет работать для поиска объектов с двумя и более вложенных элементов с одинаковым а:1